createTextFinder returning null on production
The following code from a web application works perfectly when running in the code editor but it fails when launching from the link I get on implementation. It returns TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getColumn'). So the problematic line is line 4: var col = ws.createTextFinder(fldName).findNext().getColumn();
Do you know what the problem could be?
Thank you so much.
This is the code:
function doGet(fldName='Submission ID', submissionID='', firstColumn=true, format="HTML") {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ws = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var col = ws.createTextFinder(fldName).findNext().getColumn();  // This is the problem line
  var response="";
  if (format=="HTML") response +="<table>";
  var originalData;
  if (firstColumn) {
    originalData = ws.getRange(1,1,1,ws.getLastColumn()).getValues();  
    response += getResponse(originalData, format, true);
  }
  originalData = ws.getRange(2,1,ws.getLastRow()-1,ws.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  if (submissionID != '') {
    var filteredData = originalData.filter(function(item) {
      return item[col-1]>submissionID;
    });
  }else{
    var filteredData = originalData;
  }
  response += getResponse(filteredData, format, false);
  if (format=="HTML") response +="</table>";
  return response;
}

function getResponse(rng, format="HTML", isHeader=false){
  var retValue="";
  switch (format) {
    case "JSON":
      retValue = JSON.stringify(rng);
      retValue = ContentService.createTextOutput(retValue);
      break;
    default:
      if (isHeader) retValue = "<thead>";
      rng.forEach(row=>{
        retValue += "<tr>";
          for (var col=0; col<row.length;col++){
            retValue += "<td>"+row[col]+"</td>";
          }
        retValue += "</tr>";
      })
      if (isHeader) retValue += "</thead>";
    break;
  }
  return retValue;
}

Update:
I show some screenshots that may better explain the situation
A) Development environment. It works fine:

B) Production environment. It fails


https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder#return_1

Thanks @Cooper. Yes, I know; but the data is there, in the first row of the spreadsheet. In fact, as I said: in the execution from the programming interface it ends correctly. It is in the execution in the production environment where it fails

Usually a doGet is executed by accessing an appropriate end point which in my understanding issues a trigger and provides an event object.  Perhaps in your own work locally you are just calling the doget as a normal function but in you app it is calling an endpoint and supplying an event object which is corrupting you first paramenter which is field name.

Try Logger.log on fieldname

If you are accessing active sheet from a webapp then it may not be the sheet you think it is. Logger.log(ws.getName())
